# Help me decipher ambiguities in notation from a textbook derivation of the QM momentum operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, notation

I am familiar with the momentum operator in quantum mechanics, and have used it in problems, in at least one dimension. However, I am reading a new text in effort to absorb any details about the formalization that I might not yet be aware of.

Sakurai and Napolitano in "Modern Quantum Mechanics" 3rd edition, are giving a derivation of the momentum operator effect on a vector with known position. They are starting with an expression that they derived in preceding sections, using one minus the imaginary unit times fixed momentum times displacement (over hbar)

I am having extreme difficulty trying to understand formulas 1.247, 1.248, 1.249 and 1.250 -- if this question is answered successfully I should be able to correctly interpret the rest of the page.

The authors are using the same symbol $(x')$ in three different ways in the same formula. This seems to go against all rules of notation I've ever encountered, and in this case, it creates real ambiguity.

- a free variable on the left hand side, which should be interepreted as constant, just the name of the vector component we are considering (in 1.249 and 1.250)
- the "variable" of integration in the middle (in 1.247 and 1.248); as everybody knows, these are not really variables in the greater expression, but just determine what the integral is doing to the expression integrated, i.e. how the expression is being turned into a function so that it can be integrated w.r.t. that specific variable as opposed to some other. Here $x'$ is also the symbol they chose for that
- the "variable" of differentiation on the right (in 1.247, 1.248, 1.249 and 1.250). Same problem as with the integral, not really a variable outside the scope of the formula being differentiated, as in all derivatives, but due to having the same symbol, its meaning is ambiguous here. Now there is the question as to how parentheses would close the expression:
- In addition there is a question as to where parentheses are to be inserted. The authors have taken up the habit of putting the $dx$ right next to the integral sign, which I've gotten used to, but in this case it seems ambiguous in regards to whether
- - either the derivative is its own expression and is turned into a function then integrated
- - the derivative is not part of the integral and the derivative, once taken, is just multiplied on the right of the integral expression after it is also taken, and they are separate, just two factors
- - the derivative is somehow re-taken for every point in the region integrated, and then the sum of infinitesimals of these are taken as the integral

I'm attaching the page in question from the above text

I was hoping someone would provide the same formula but using notation with three different names for variables in these three different contexts of the formulas.

Of course I know the simple one-dimensional momentum operator expression that you can get on Wikipedia. But I was hoping someone would clarify this in a way that I can understand what point the authors are trying to make. Clearly there is something important to be learned concerning deriving it in this specific way, that is supposed to be more general.

[image: Page in question]

Comment: I confess your question is far more obscure than the authors' paradigmatic, crystal-clear usage. You *must* appreciate the variable *x* and the constant *Δx* have nothing to do with each other, except the latter may add to the former. Otherwise, the variable *x* may enter a ket, $|x\rangle$ as the eigenvalue of it under action by the operator $\hat x$. The ket is, of course, a function of *x*, and can be differentiated, integrated, etc. , w.r.t. it. There is a single, consistent usage. Can you explain what you are misreading?

Comment: I agree with Cosmas that Sakurai is being very clear here; your problems seem to completely just stem from them choosing to use $\Delta x^\prime$; the solution is very simple and straight forward, just do a swap of all appearances of $\Delta x^\prime=$ some other symbol, and then every other thing will be necessarily there and cannot be improved.

Comment: I would like to emphasise that it is nice to see a question that had this much work put into it. You are being thorough, and that is appreciated. It is just that you happened to be asking for something that is inimical to this particular presentation.

Comment: Just to reiterate what others have said, in Sakurai's presentation, $\Delta x'$ and $x'$ are *different, independent variables*. I believe your confusion will be cleared up when you account for this. You may want to try rewriting the formulas using a different letter for the integration variable.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I think I understand the derivation better thanks to your pointing out what the problem was =not=. However, the problem was not delta-X that I was concerned with. It was the introduction of the derivative wrt dx in the last line of 1.247, vs. line before, which has nothing to do with delta-X. Any of you can probably address my question by answering the following. Are they using the Fundamental Theorem of Calc backwards? Usually you don't see d/dx w integral over the same variable together, and it creates a bra whose values is a symbol bound to two containing expressions